# How to change Ubuntu Budgie's Plank launcher command line parameters?

Tags: launcher, budgie, plank

I would like to run Tilix with param `--session=~/my-tilix-config.json` with mouse clicking Plank's launcher. I found that references to launchers visible in Plank are kept in `~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/`. Each `*.dockitem` file is just a simple text file with path to `*.desktop`. In my case I changed `com.gexperts.Tilix.dockitem` content to:

```
[PlankDockItemPreferences]
Launcher=file:///home/user/.local/share/applications/com.gexperts.Tilix.desktop
```

Next I went to aforementioned path and changed the proper launcher to

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=Tilix
Comment=A tiling terminal for Gnome
Icon=com.gexperts.Tilix
DBusActivatable=true
Exec=tilix --session=/home/user/.config/tilix.json
Actions=new-window;new-session;
Categories=System;TerminalEmulator;X-GNOME-Utilities;
Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;
StartupNotify=true

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=tilix --action=app-new-window --session=/home/user/.config/tilix.json

[Desktop Action new-session]
Name=New Session
Exec=tilix --action=app-new-session --session=/home/user/.config/tilix.json
```

I checked that running `tilix --action=app-new-session --session=/home/user/.config/tilix.json` opens Tilix reconfigured with my config, then I logged out and logged in again to make sure settings were applied. When I click Tilix launcher passed argument does not work - it just runs Tilix in standard single mode (my config makes Tilix splitted into 4 quarters)

#### How can I launch Tilix with param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I'd try :

```
Exec="tilix --session=/home/user/.config/tilix.json"
```

Second thing I think about - as Budgie does not seem to immediately "update" .desktop files in panels and probably docks:

unpin from plank your actual Tilix launcher,

Launch Tilix from your customized launcher in `~/.local/share/applications`, then pin it to plank.

Comment: Thanks! It all happen to be wrong access modes on files and folders. I had to do something with sudo because I screwed the modes. When I did `ls -l` I got it on display and corrected.